# ColdFusion cffile upload - optional

Tags: coldfusion, cffile

I've created an online application which works well as long as someone has uploaded a resume. We now have positions available where a resume is optional, but the system throws an error if there's no file in the que.

I've tried IsDefined and StructKeyExists and can't get it to work. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated...

```
<cfset destination = expandPath("./uploads")>
<cfif IsDefined('form.submitapp')>
        <cfif IsDefined("form.uploadfile")>
            <cffile action="upload" filefield="uploadfile" destination="#destination#" nameConflict="makeUnique">
            <cfif isDefined("CFFILE.serverFile")>
            <cfset form.resume = CFFILE.serverFile>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>

  <cfinsert tablename=...
```

Comment: Share your form code. Always share your form code. Do you have a cfparam for form.submitapp and form.uploadfile? If so, that's likely your problem.

Comment: Also, keep in mind "empty" is a different concept than "undefined". Most (not all) form fields will be submitted, regardless of whether they contain a value. That means they *will* be defined on the action page. They will just have a value of an empty string ie "". Functions like `structKeyExists` do not check the field *value*. They check whether a field is defined. So be sure you are using the correct comparisons for the job.

Comment: The fact that you are using cfinsert instead of cfquery reduces your flexibility for handling things like optional form fields.

Comment: Also, once you resolve this, because this is an easily solvable problem, it's a good idea to put the CFFILE and subsequent cfset inside a CFTRY/Catch like `<cftry><cffile...><cfset....><cfcatch>An error with the upload occurred.</cfcatch></cftry>`. Resolve this problem first so you're not trapping a simple logical error.

Answer (score 0):

As bracketsage said - you probably have a default in place. Try this:

```
<cfset destination = expandPath("./uploads")>
<cfif IsDefined('form.submitapp')>
  <cfif IsDefined("form.uploadfile") AND len(trim(form.uploadFile))>
  <cffile action="upload" filefield="uploadfile" destination="#destination#" nameConflict="makeUnique">
    <cfif isDefined("CFFILE.serverFile")>
      <cfset form.resume = CFFILE.serverFile>
    </cfif>
  </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the actual form and error message (hint,hint ;-) but an error could occur even without a `cfparam`. The file field will still be defined, even if it is left empty. That will cause an error when they call `cffile action="upload"`. The `len(trim(..))` check above should avoid that problem. @BigMike - There is no need for `isDefined("CFFILE.serverFile")`. That is a system variable that is always defined after a successful upload.